# Pandas head with offset

Tags: python, pandas

What is the suggested way to get, for example, the first X rows after an offset of Y? What I'm currently doing is:

```
offset, limit = 2, 2
df=pd.DataFrame([{'a':1}, {'a': 2}, {'a':3}, {'a': 4}, {'a':5}])
df.head(offset+limit)[offset:]
#    a
# 2  3
# 3  4
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @wwnde I suppose, but that gives the wrong answer when I try. `df.loc[2:3]` gives the correct answer.

Comment: IIUC, then this should work `df.iloc[offset:offset+limit]`.

Comment: @Ch3steR yes, thank you that's what I was looking for. Would you want to post an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) here.

```
df.iloc[offset: offset+limit]

   a
2  3
3  4
```

Comment: `df.iloc`, i is for integer columns' indices.Because we do not call columns here, `df.loc` could still work.